# How to check if a port is available during installation using Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am trying to create a setup file, so that during installation it will check a port, say 9000, and let user know the port status.
I am new to Inno Setup and wonder if this is possible, and how would I check for this?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to use pascal in inno-setup to check on port?

Answer (score 6):

you can use my function to check a port is available

see :

```
  function CheckPortOccupied(Port:String):Boolean;
  var
    ResultCode: Integer;
  begin
   Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C netstat -na | findstr'+' /C:":'+Port+' "', '',0,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    if ResultCode  <> 1 then 
    begin
      Log('this port('+Port+') is occupied');
      Result := True; 
    end else
    begin
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to see if a port is available is to try connecting or listening to it (depending on what kind of availability you're checking for).

You can do this with WinAPI calls directly, but you'd probably find it easier to write the code to test the port into a DLL using the language of your choice (provided that it can create native DLLs of course), and then [call this from within Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For windows 2000, xp versions you can use telnet command, if win 7, vista, the telnet is not enabled by default, the user needs to enable it from control panel or you can use `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"` to enable it thru command line. from inno you can check the windows version and run the commands accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modification to code from @LEo, it now checks for

1. TCP port (for UDP, just change to 'netstat -anp UDP' instead)
2. port at localhost (127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0)

Here is my implementation:

```
// check TCP port availability (1-65535), return false if occupied
function CheckPortOccupied(Port: String): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
 Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C netstat -anp TCP | findstr /r "127.0.0.1:' + Port + '\> 0.0.0.0:' + Port + '\>"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  if ResultCode  <> 1 then 
  begin
    Log('TCP port '+Port+' is occupied');
    Result := True; 
  end else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

// port should be in valid range and not occupied
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { Validate certain pages before allowing the user to proceed }
  if CurPageID = UserPage.ID then begin
    if UserPage.Values[0] = '' then begin
      MsgBox('You must enter a listening TCP port.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end else begin
      { Check TCP port availability before allowing the user to proceed }
      Port := StrToInt(UserPage.Values[0]);

      if (Port < 1) or (Port > 65535) then begin
        MsgBox('Please enter a valid TCP port number between 1 and 65535.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end else if CheckPortOccupied(IntToStr(Port)) then begin
        MsgBox('TCP Port ' + IntToStr(Port) + ' is already occupied. Please choose another port.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end else begin
        Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: You may need to update the comment on the function as it returns true, not false, if the port is occupied :-)