# how to check port is free/open in inno setup script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

how to check port is free /open in inno setup creation.

For example i tried to get os version **GetWindowsVersionString()**

Is there is any option is available to check if the port 8080 is free for installing tomcat service.

Comment: Wait, how is `GetWindowsVersionString` related to what you want to do ? Anyway, it was already [`asked here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12844955/960757).

Comment: @TLama First of all thanks for your prev post. Come ur question, my software will not work under Windows 2000 so i ll get ur ver id then process need to install or not.

Comment: @TLama Can you share sample code installing mysql binary and tomcat binary as a windows service

Comment: @G Jay, I have no such code, so I have nothing to share. Before asking me you might look around. I think there was a bunch of questions about MySQL and a few about Tomcat. And yes, my promised Windows API service controller is still pending on my to-do list :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use my function to check port is free /open in inno setup
see :

```
function CheckPortOccupied(Port:String):Boolean;
var
ResultCode: Integer;
begin
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C netstat -na | findstr'+' /C:":'+Port+' "', '', 0,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
if ResultCode <> 1 then
begin
Log('this port('+Port+') is occupied');
Result := True;
end else
begin
Result := False;
end;
end;
```